# Do derived classes contain the member variables of their base class?

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I have a base class foo:

```
class foo {
   foo(int n) : child(n) {};

  protected:
   int child;
}
```

Now I have a child class bar:

```
class bar : public foo {
  bar(int n) : foo(n) { }
}
```

Does bar have a data member child?
If so is it initialized to be n?

Comment: Can't you check with a compiler?

Comment: Yes, `bar` is a `foo`, so it also has `child`. I suggest you start learning with a book.

Comment: Yes (because it inherits from `foo`), and Yes (because foo's constructor initializes it, and bar's constructor properly invoke foo's).

Comment: of course, if you inherit a base class you also inherit its protected members by default

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is yes, which can very easily be checked.

If you say:

```
class bar : public foo {
  bar(int n) : foo(n) { }
  print_child() {std::cout << child << std::endl;}
}

int main() {
  bar test(5);
  test.print_child();
  return 0;
}
```

You will see that it prints 5.

What you are asking about here is some of the core of OO, public inheritance is a is-a relationship. That means that mean that your `bar` is-a `foo` which also means that the bar object will carry with it all of foos members.

This of course doesn't mean that you will have access to all of `foo`s members. You have used the `public` and `protected` section of the class. But all members that are in the `private`section are not accessible even by its subclasses. This are normally done to hide implementation details for the user of the base class.

As you have observed when calling the super class constructor in the way you do initializes the base objects members.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes to both questions. bar is a foo and thus has all members that foo has. The constructor for bar calls the constructor for foo and sets value for child.

Answer (score 0):

E.g: `bar bobj(10);` will have have `child` and it will be initialized with say `10` in this case.

The constructor of bar would call the constructor of foo and pass n and then the constructor of foo would initialize the variable with `n`.

Inheritance means the whatever the base class has the derived class has. The data members when the objects are created. And the `static` object, static methods and non static methods.

When you define new type in c++ you define what data the type should have, what operations should be allowed on that data and how the type and it's data should be constructed.

Inheritance will help when on type has to be created based on another type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Inheritance means, a `bar` is a `foo`, plus maybe a bit more. In your case, that "bit" is only a constructor for `bar`. In C++ that inheritance is implemented in such a way that a `bar` contains a subobject of type `foo`. And since that subobject has a `child`, the `bar` *indirectly* has that `child` as well. It *directly* contains only a `foo` and a constructor.
Since you initialize the `foo` subobject in the constructor, and that in turn initializes its `child`, the `bar` constructor indeed initializes the `child` indirectly.

Access modifiers aside, you could access that `child` via a `bar` easly:

```
bar b;
b.child = 5;
```

But since `child` is protected in `foo`, you cannot access it from the outside, but you can from `bar`'s methods:

```
class bar : public foo {
  bar(int n) : foo(n) { }
  void baz() { child = 42; } //this is allowed.
}
```